# How to Post to Json server Db particular format and get response in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to post the data in a particular format here is my format

```
 {
        "Authentication": {
          "Username": "*****",
          "Password": "****"
        },
      "File": {
        "Orders": [{
               "Status":"",

            }]
      },
       "OrderID":16,
          "RequestType": 6
      }
```

How to post the data in this format and get the response .I tried in this way

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                        object.put("Username", "******");
                        object.put("Password", "*******");
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                        jsonObject.put("Authentication", object);
                        jsonObject.put("OrderID", data);
                        jsonObject.put("RequestType", 6);
                        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
                        postMethod.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString()));
                        postMethod.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                        postMethod.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
                     entity = response.getEntity();
                    response_value = EntityUtils.toString(entity).toString();
                       Log.e(TAG, response_value);
```

I dont Know how to add the file object in that ,if you have any idea help me

Comment: Please add more description to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You just POST the JSON string to the server and specify the correct header

```
application/json
```

The format of the json should be received by the server in the same format as it was sent.

Comment: how to can i specify the header

Answer (score 0):

Use `toString()` to convert your json object to String.

Example :

```
                String jsonObjString = jsonObject.toString();

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://thisisasampleurl.com");
                HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(jsonObjectString
                        .getBytes("UTF-8"));
                post.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response
                        .getEntity());
```

You already have the required headers in your code.